# Predict scores for documents?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I have a set of documents and their corresponding scores, which are something very similar to the number of upvote/downvote on SO. I'd like to build a system that is able to predict the score given a document. Some machine learning approaches for regression, and natural language processing techniques for deriving useful features from the document might be helpful.

Is there any state-of-art method for such problem? I had done some searches on Google Scholar but failed to find a satisfying result.

Thanks.

Comment: Try bag-of-words with tf-idf weights and start with a simple linear regression. If that doesn't work well enough, start looking into fancier methods. Be sure to plot your data.

Comment: Thanks. I definitely will try that, but I just wanted to know what state-of-the-art approaches are out there.

Answer (score 2):

Predicting the quality or usefulness of an answer is still very difficult to do. The algorithms aren't different from other machine learning problems: people are just using standard regression-based techniques. It's really going to come down to a lot of feature extraction. For example, to predict the number of votes for a story on a news aggregator like reddit or digg you might want to see if the topic of the post is about a trending news story. If the trend is over, it probably won't get many votes.

You're going to have to get creative about what features will be useful in the domain your working in. You can try things like the complexity of the language that the author is using. You can measure that through the average number of words per sentence, the average length of a word, maybe the total number of words in the document. You can try running it through a spell checker: maybe documents with a lot of misspellings get downvoted.

There are several research areas to search on Google Scholar:

- automated essay grading
- predicting the popularity of stories on Digg
- predicting the number of retweets a tweet will get

There have also been several data science competitions recently on this topic on kaggle.com. The user forums usually have really good information about how they approached these things. Here's one on  [automated essay scoring](http://www.kaggle.com/c/asap-aes).